# Gentoo failed to emerge sys-devel/prelink-20130503

Tags: gentoo, emerge, portage

I'm trying to install `app-emulation/wine` Gentoo package using command:

```
sudo WINE_COMMIT="wine-2.0-rc5" STAGING_COMMIT="v2.0-rc5" emerge -av '=app-emulation/wine-9999'
```

but compilation of `sys-devel/prelink-20130503` is failed.

Maybe these informations will be useful:

Global USE flags that are set in **/etc/portage/make.conf**:

```
userlocales unicode nls tools X a52 aac acl acpi alsa amd64 berkdb -bindist bluetooth branding bzip2 cairo cdda cdr cli colord consolekit cracklib crypt cups cxx dbus dri dts dvd dvdr eds emboss encode evo exif fam firefox flac fortran gdbm gif glamor -gnome -gnome-keyring -gnome-online-accounts gpm gstreamer gtk iconv introspection ipv6 jpeg lcms ldap libnotify libsecret mad mng modules mp3 mp4 mpeg multilib nautilus ncurses nptl ogg opengl openmp pam pango pcre pdf png policykit ppds -pulseaudio qt3support qt4 readline sdl seccomp session spell ssl startup-notification svg -systemd tcpd tiff tracker truetype udev udisks upower usb vorbis wxwidgets x264 xattr xcb xml xv xvid zlib savedconfig xinerama python cjk wifi hardened jack startup-notification custom-cflags java postgres curl lzma socks5 perl v4l fontconfig gphoto2 gsm nls odbc openal scanner threads vaapi xcomposite
```

Local USE flags that were set for `=app-emulation/wine-9999` in **/etc/portage/package.use/wine**:

```
capi custom-cflags d3d9 dos gecko gstreamer mono netapi opencl osmesa pcap perl pipelight prelink realtime run-exes s3tc samba staging themes udev
```

Gentoo profile is `default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop`.

The result of command `sudo emerge --info '=sys-devel/prelink-20130503::gentoo'`:

```
Portage 2.3.8 (python 3.4.5-final-0, default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop, gcc-5.4.0, glibc-2.23-r4, 4.12.12-gentoo x86_64)
=================================================================
                         System Settings
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-4.12.12-gentoo-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-_i5-6300HQ_CPU_@_2.30GHz-with-gentoo-2.3
KiB Mem:     8052428 total,   5024888 free
KiB Swap:   12582908 total,  12582908 free
Timestamp of repository gentoo: Sat, 30 Sep 2017 00:30:01 +0000
Head commit of repository gentoo: bca08ede4c45bd466b21bc0a9160e90ce14226bc
sh bash 4.3_p48-r1
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.28.1 p1.0) 2.28.1
app-shells/bash:          4.3_p48-r1::gentoo
dev-java/java-config:     2.2.0-r3::gentoo
dev-lang/perl:            5.24.1-r2::gentoo
dev-lang/python:          2.7.12::gentoo, 3.4.5::gentoo
dev-util/cmake:           3.7.2::gentoo
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.28-r2::gentoo
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.3::gentoo
sys-apps/openrc:          0.28::gentoo
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.10-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.13::gentoo, 2.69::gentoo
sys-devel/automake:       1.11.6-r1::gentoo, 1.15-r2::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils:       2.28.1::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc:            5.4.0-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc-config:     1.7.3::gentoo
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4.6-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/make:           4.2.1::gentoo
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 4.4::gentoo (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.23-r4::gentoo
Repositories:

gentoo
    location: /usr/portage
    sync-type: rsync
    sync-uri: rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage
    priority: -1000

dotnet
    location: /var/lib/layman/dotnet
    sync-type: laymansync
    sync-uri: https://anongit.gentoo.org/git/proj/dotnet.git
    masters: gentoo
    priority: 50

fw-overlay
    location: /var/lib/layman/fw-overlay
    sync-type: laymansync
    sync-uri: https://github.com/no-hope/fw-overlay.git
    masters: gentoo
    priority: 50

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/dconf /etc/env.d /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo /etc/texmf/language.dat.d /etc/texmf/language.def.d /etc/texmf/updmap.d /etc/texmf/web2c /usr/bin/startx"
CXXFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
FCFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs clean-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles merge-sync multilib-strict news parallel-fetch preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms split-log strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync webrsync-gpg xattr"
FFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://gentoo.prz.rzeszow.pl rsync://gentoo.prz.rzeszow.pl/gentoo rsync://ftp.vectranet.pl/gentoo/ http://ftp.vectranet.pl/gentoo/ ftp://ftp.vectranet.pl/gentoo/"
LANG="en_GB.utf8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="-j5"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages --exclude=/.git"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
USE="X a52 aac acl acpi alsa amd64 berkdb bluetooth branding bzip2 cairo cdda cdr cjk cli colord consolekit cracklib crypt cups curl custom-cflags cxx dbus dri dts dvd dvdr eds emboss encode evo exif fam firefox flac fontconfig fortran gdbm gif glamor gphoto2 gpm gsm gstreamer gtk hardened iconv introspection ipv6 jack java jpeg lcms ldap libnotify libsecret lzma mad mng modules mp3 mp4 mpeg multilib nautilus ncurses nls nptl odbc ogg openal opengl openmp pam pango pcre pdf perl png policykit postgres ppds python qt3support qt4 readline savedconfig scanner sdl seccomp session socks5 spell ssl startup-notification svg tcpd threads tiff tools tracker truetype udev udisks unicode upower usb userlocales v4l vaapi vorbis wifi wxwidgets x264 xattr xcb xcomposite xinerama xml xv xvid zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="kexi words flow plan sheets stage tables krita karbon braindump author" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="mmx mmxext sse sse2" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock isync itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput synaptics evdev mouse keyboard" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-6" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres9_5" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_4" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby22" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="nvidia" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CC, CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, CXX, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS
```

The result of command `sudo emerge -pqv '=sys-devel/prelink-20130503::gentoo'`:

```
[ebuild  N    ] sys-devel/prelink-20130503  USE="(-selinux)" 

 * IMPORTANT: 2 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.
```

Portage logs (I pasted it to external website because there's length of post is limited): https://paste.pound-python.org/show/ZIPYnnlLfOhL196ENBPu/

I'm counting for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.gentoo.org/627576 — make sure you're using `dev-libs/elfutils-0.170-r1` and it should work.